# Concatenate columns with t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

[image]

I need to write a query grouping by Code, DateCod, Room and NumberOfBeds.

For the Name column I need to concatenate names, same action for Booking column and for Num column I need to sum

The result should be the following

[image]

I'm trying the `FOR XML PATH('')` approach but I can't find the solution. Can someone suggest me a way to do that ?

Best regards and thanks a lot
Fab

Comment: For XML PATH is the right route, can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STUFF` with `FOR XML PATH('')` to achieve this.

**Query**

```
select 
  t.[Code], 
  t.[DateCod],
  t.[Room],
  t.[NrBeds],
  stuff((select ',' + t.[Name]
    from [your_table_name] t1
    where t1.[Code] = t.[Code]
    for xml path, type).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as [Name],
  stuff((select ',' + t.[Booking]
    from [your_table_name] t1
    where t1.[Code] = t.[Code]
    for xml path, type).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as [Booking],
  sum(t.Num) as [Num]
from [your_table_name] t
group by t.[Code], t.[DateCod], t.[Room], t.[NrBeds];
```